# Mapear propriedades java.time com Hibernate e/ou JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, api, jpa

Há alguma forma de mapear propriedades como `java.time.LocalDate` e/ou `java.time.Instant` por meio do JPA e/ou Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize os Converters do JPA 2.1. Com eles é possível mapear os tipos que você quiser.

Funciona como se fosse um Converter de JPA.

Seria algo como:

```
@Converter
public class CoverConverter implements AttributeConverter<Cover, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Cover attribute) {
        switch (attribute) {
            case DUST_JACKET:
                return "D";
            case HARDCOVER:
                return "H";
            case PAPERBACK:
                return "P";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown" + attribute);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Cover convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        switch (dbData) {
            case "D":
                return DUST_JACKET;
            case "H":
                return HARDCOVER;
            case "P":
                return PAPERBACK;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown" + dbData);
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter.html
http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/06/mapping-enums-done-right-with-convert.html

Apenas tome cuidado para não confundir com o Converter nativo do hibernate. O problema de usar o converter nativo do hibernate é que você não poderá fazer a portabilidade do seu projeto para outra implementação.

Answer (score 2):

Até onde eu sei (e pesquisei) ainda não é possível mapear, as novas classes de data que foram adicionadas no Java 8.
De uma olhada [AQUI](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-63).

Vale a pena dar uma olhada nas implementações específicas do Hibernate ou Eclipselink para obter alguma novidade.

Fora isso, ainda não vejo o porque usar `java.time.*` ao invés do velho `java.util.Date`, você pode usar o `JodaTime` para facilitar a vida, ou até fazer uma conversão para o tipo que você precisa, já que no fim das contas você tem um `long` correspondente ao milisecs

Answer (score 0):

É possível utilizar os converters com o pacote java.sql.* segundo [esse link](https://bitbucket.org/montanajava/jpaattributeconverters).

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDatePersistenceConverter implements
    AttributeConverter<java.time.LocalDate, java.sql.Date> {

    @Override
    public java.sql.Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate entityValue) {
       return java.sql.Date.valueOf(entityValue);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(java.sql.Date databaseValue) {
        return databaseValue.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```